# Whats the computer science term for increase in timeouts?

Tags: email, timeout

I can't remember the computer science term for increasing timeouts for example sending email.

First it starts of at 5seconds, then 10 seconds, then 20 seconds, then 1minute etc.

What is the term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

exponential back-off

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff